# AFNetworking and sending array error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to do a post and am including an array in my NSDictionary for the parameters being sent but get this error? Not sure why, I can only assume because passing in an array might be causing issues.

This is my code:

```
NSArray *categoriesSelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"categories"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userId": userId, @"categories": categoriesSelected};
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; // if response JSON format
[manager GET:@"http://kinglior.herokuapp.com/home" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
           NSLog(@"Data saved");



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[op start];
```

The error:

Data passed like so:

```
2014-04-24 02:23:45.962 Stand[1231:60b] params being sent: {

        categories =     (
            human,
            flesh
        );
        userId = 535341502ac8590200e0e7b5;
    }
```

UPDATED THE ERROR FOR SERVER SIDE:
The Error

```
    [ 'Technology', 'Fashion' ]
2014-04-25T02:09:13.950380+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T
2014-04-25T02:09:13.963250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/home?categories[]=Technology&categories[]=Fashion&userId=535341502ac8590200e0e7b5 host=kinglior.herokuapp.com request_id=af7e2f9f-17f4-401d-b444-25926a4989f2 fwd="37.142.32.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=937
```

I am expecting it to be received by the serverside like so ["human", "flesh"] ... I am definitely sending it wrong, as I am calling JSON.parse() on the server side. Anyone able to tell me how I can send it like so?

UPDATE:

This worked for me...

```
NSArray *categoriesSelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"categories"];
NSError* error;

    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:categoriesSelected options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: Wrap everything in a single JSON object. For example: { "data": { "userId": ..., "categories": [] } }

Comment: I updated the error to show the server-side if that clears up anything if not how do I attempt what you said because I think it already wraps it for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want the request parameters to be serialized in JSON (i.e. if the server is expecting content-type 'application/json'), you need to use `AFJSONRequestSerializer`

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: I just tried that same issue... look at my updated code I added it in

Comment: Well apparently adding iOS's serialization worked not sure why AF's is not working for me